# phpmyadmin: data is not importing correctly for varchar(utf8_bin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed latest mysql and phpmyadmin 3.3.2deb1 on ubuntu. When I import already created sql file of data then it store garbage data (for example: 416e746967756120616e642042617262756461) for varchar field but all other fields are successfully imported. When I used same file before latest installation then it was importing data correctly for all fields.

Any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the SQL file come from?

Comment: I created it from Export option in previous phpmyadmin version. It contains only data to insert. Structure is imported before data import with another file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not garbage data, it's a hex-encoded string `Antigua and Barbuda`.

It sounds like you've exported a BLOB column (traditionally specified in a `x'416e'`-style hex literal as it may contain nasty control codes and bytes that are not necessarily valid in a given character encoding), but imported it into a normal text (`VARCHAR`) column.

What's in the SQL file? Look for the hex string and check the syntax around it.